# cpu is always at high consumption 50% - 90%, what can be checked for solving?

Tags: performance, cpu-load

My platform: Host: Ubuntu 14.04.2
Virtualbox ubuntu 14.10. The cpu of the client 14.10 is always reach at high consumption, although no app running. After a start up, I launch nothing, the cpu is about 50% to 90% causing slowly.

Could you help, what item should be check for clues?

Comment: You can run `top` to see which process is using the CPU heavily. It might possibly be because the VM is using software rendering. Could you open Details from System Settings and tell us what's under "Graphics"?

Comment: Yes  zhongfu, that's the "Gallium 0.4  on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits)"

Comment: That means that your VM is using CPU software rendering. Did you enable 2D graphics acceleration in VirtualBox?

Comment: Not yet. Should it be enable, of rationality?

Comment: You should enable 2D (and maybe 3D) acceleration and also install the VBox guest additions in the VM. Software rendering takes up a lot of CPU cycles.

Comment: I can only enable 3D, the 2D is impossible with a message: "Invalid setting detected". The situation is clearly improved now. cpu is just a few %.

Comment: What's displayed under "Graphics" now?

Comment: Chromium, it's changed.

Comment: Alright. This means that you're now using the VirtualBox OpenGL drivers now, so your high CPU usage problem should be rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htop`, which can be installed and run from the Terminal, can be used to show you what apps use a lot of the CPU. It has scrolling, which makes it easier to use than `top`.
`System Monitor` is a built in application that is the equivalent to `Windows Task Manager`, and is a graphical alternative to `top` and `htop`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty good laptop running 14.04 I put 14.10 on it and the same thing happened, I would just put 14.04 back on it and maybe try 15.04 when it comes out.